# Tomcat error 404 "did not find a matching property"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I have an error when I deploy my java application in Tom Cat. When I run as choosing the server, it give me "HTTP Status 404" with these warnings:

```html
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FoodDrinkDispener' did not find a matching property.
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server built:          Mar 18 2016 20:31:49 UTC
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server number:         8.0.33.0
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: OS Version:            6.3
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Architecture:          amd64
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: JVM Version:           1.8.0_51-b16
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Giacomo B\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp5
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Giacomo B\Desktop\Appunti su ingegneria\Computer Engineering\2015-2016\Ingegneria del sw\apache-tomcat-8.0.33
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Giacomo B\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp5
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Giacomo B\Desktop\Appunti su ingegneria\Computer Engineering\2015-2016\Ingegneria del sw\apache-tomcat-8.0.33
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Giacomo B\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp5\wtpwebapps
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Giacomo B\Desktop\Appunti su ingegneria\Computer Engineering\2015-2016\Ingegneria del sw\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\endorsed
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAZIONI: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\polyspace\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\Users\Giacomo B\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Giacomo B\Desktop\Appunti su ingegneria\Computer Engineering\2015-2016\Ingegneria del sw\eclipse;;.
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAZIONI: Initialization processed in 474 ms
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting service Catalina
nov 30, 2016 2:07:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
nov 30, 2016 2:07:23 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
nov 30, 2016 2:07:23 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFORMAZIONI: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  it.jack.fdd.controller
nov 30, 2016 2:07:23 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFORMAZIONI: Root resource classes found:
  class it.jack.fdd.controller.CountryController
nov 30, 2016 2:07:23 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFORMAZIONI: No provider classes found.
nov 30, 2016 2:07:23 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFORMAZIONI: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18.3 12/01/2014 08:23 AM'
nov 30, 2016 2:07:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
nov 30, 2016 2:07:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
nov 30, 2016 2:07:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAZIONI: Server startup in 2000 ms
```

in particular I think that my problem is `AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FoodDrinkDispener' did not find a matching property.`

In fact I searched on internet and I found several possible solutions, such as:

> Remove the project from the server from the Server View. Right click on server -> add and remove, Then run the project under the same server.
>   Or if warning still remains then
>   Go to server view
>   Double click on your tomcat server. It will open the server configuration.
>   Under server options check ‘Publish module contents to separate XML files’ checkbox. 
>   Restart your server. This time your page will come without any issues. 
>   Read more http://www.java2blog.com/2016/03/restful-web-services-jaxrs-crud-example.html

But this does not solve the problem. I spent several hours to search to fix it, but nothing.
This is my pom.xml:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>it.jack.fdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>FoodDrinkDispener</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FoodDrinkDispener Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  
   <properties>  
        <jersey.version>1.18.3</jersey.version>  
    </properties>  
 <dependencies>  
  <dependency>  
   <groupId>junit</groupId>  
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
   <version>3.8.1</version>  
   <scope>test</scope>  
  </dependency>  
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

    
  <dependency>  
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>  
   <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>  
   <version>${jersey.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  
  <dependency>  
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>  
   <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>  
   <version>${jersey.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  
  
  <dependency>  
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>  
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>  
   <version>1.2</version>  
  </dependency>  
 </dependencies>  
 <build>  
  <finalName>FoodDrinkDispener</finalName>  
  <plugins>  
   <plugin>  
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>3.3</version>  
    <configuration>  
     <source>1.7</source>  
     <target>1.7</target>  
    </configuration>  
   </plugin>  
   <plugin>  
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>  
    <configuration>  
     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>  
    </configuration>  
   </plugin>  
  </plugins>  
 </build>  
  
</project>
```

This is my web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
 version="3.0">  
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>  
 <servlet>  
  <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
  <init-param>  
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>  
   <param-value>it.jack.fdd.controller</param-value>  
  </init-param>  
  <init-param>  
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>  
   <param-value>true</param-value>  
  </init-param>  
    
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
 </servlet>  
 <servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>  
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
 </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

And this is my server configurations: (server.xml)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>

     <!--   <Context docBase="JAXRSJsonCRUDExample" path="/JAXRSJsonExample" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JAXRSJsonCRUDExample"/><Context docBase="helloworld" path="/helloworld" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:helloworld"/>   --> 
      
     <!--   <Context docBase="FoodDrinkDispener" path="/JAXRSJsonExample" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FoodDrinkDispener"/>  --> 
 <!--     <Context docBase="FoodDrinkDispener" path="/FoodDrinkDispener" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FoodDrinkDispener"/>  --> 
     <Context docBase="FoodDrinkDispener" path="/FoodDrinkDispener" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FoodDrinkDispener"/></Host>
          </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I whish that someone can help me to fix this error.

Comment: you should not need to edit your `server.xml` - reset this to the original.  Have you used maven to build your `target` ?

Comment: You mean: ->Maven ->Update Project ?

Comment: No `Run->Maven Build`

Comment: I do yet "Maven Build" with goal as "Clean Install". I have to use a different goal?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the html file, try to change your html file name to `index.html` so the server will understand it.